# How to batch rename files using bash

Tags: bash, batch, zsh, rename

I know there are lots of such questions, but I couldn't find one (or a combination of several), which describes the things I want to do. I think I need to use regular expressions, but I am not very good with that. I use zsh. I have a folder with files, which I want to rename:

- I want the files `challenge1.rb`, `challenge2.rb`, `challenge3.rb`, etc. to be renamed to `c1.rb`, `c2.rb` etc. Similarly `task1.rb` and similar must be renamed to `t1.rb` etc.
- `sample_spec_c1.rb`, `sample_spec_c2.rb` etc. must be renamed to `c1_spec.rb`, `c2_spec.rb` etc.

So I guess I need some combination of regular expressions and iteration, but I don't know how to write the bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short script which will do what you want. You can call the script with a list of files like: `./scriptname *.rb` or with directories (it will recurse them): `./scriptname .`

Do not forget to set the executable bit: `chmod a+x scriptname`.

```
#!/bin/sh

suff=rb     # suffix of files to rename

script="$0" # this script name for recursion

for f in "$@" ; do
    if test -d "$f" ; then
        echo "=== recursing directory $f"
        find "$f" -type f -name "*.$suff" -exec "$script" {} +
    elif test -f "$f" ; then
        d="$(dirname "$f")"
        b="$(basename "$f")"
        r="$(echo "$b" | sed -r "s/^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]+\.${suff})\$/\1\2/;s/^[a-zA-Z]+_([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)(\.${suff})\$/\2_\1\3/")"
        echo "-- renaming $f -> $d/$r"
        mv "$f" "$d/$r"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I am sorry, there was a typo: `mv "$f" "$d/$f"`. It was renaming to the same name. Now it is corrected. I also made the regex more precise (string beginning and end specified).